# JavaScript style wrapping in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I'm primarily a JS developer, using PHP for that server-side kick and I'm looking to see if there's an method in PHP similar to the JS:

```
var something = {
    action1: function() { alert('Fire 1!'); },
    action2: function() { alert('Fire 2!'); },
    action3: function() { alert('Fire 3!'); }
}
```

Then allowing me to call like:

```
something.action2();  // Alerts 'Fire 2!'
```

It's for a relatively small app I'm working on and I'd like to avoid building classes. Since PHP is such a small part I'd like to keep it as similar in code-style as possible.

Comment: If you wish, you can write JavaScript on server side with Node.js http://nodejs.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does not have the same form of objects that JavaScript does, as PHP is a [class-based language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming), while JavaScript is a [prototype-based language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming). What this essentially means is that PHP creates objects by instantiating a class. JavaScript, however, has objects that are then cloned to create new objects.

If you wish to keep your code understandable, I'd recommend using PHP classes:

```
class SomeClass {
    function alert($string) {
        // Do something
    }
    function action1() {
        $this->alert('Fire 1!');
    }
    function action2() {
        $this->alert('Fire 2!');
    }
    function action3() {
        $this->alert('Fire 3!');
    }
}

$something = new SomeClass();
$something->action2(); // Runs the action2 function of your object
```

Comment: That's kinda what I thought, so I'll give that a run. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 3):

Using an associative array and anonymous functions (must have at least PHP 5.3) would work for you:

```
$arr = array(
    'action1' => function() { echo "Fire 1\n"; },
    'action2' => function() { echo "Fire 2\n"; },
    'action3' => function() { echo "Fire 3\n"; }
);

$arr['action1'](); // Fire 1
```

Keep in mind that you will not able to access the other functions or items of the array from the functions using `$this` (`this` in JavaScript).

Perhaps if you gave us more details on what you are looking to do, we could give some better examples.

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps a static class?

```
<?php
class something {
    public static function action1 () {
        echo 'Fire 1';
    }

    public static function action2 () {
        echo 'Fire 2';
    }

    public static function action3 () {
        echo 'Fire 3';
    }
}

something::action1();
something::action2();
something::action3();
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work (assuming you want to create 3 alerts like that :P).

```
<?php
//Array of Functions
$a = array
(
    'action1' => function() { echo "<script>alert('Fire 1!');</script>"; },
    'action2' => function() { echo "<script>alert('Fire 2!');</script>"; },
    'action3' => function() { echo "<script>alert('Fire 3!');</script>"; }
);

$a['action1'](); // Fire 1
$a['action2'](); // Fire 2
$a['action3'](); // Fire 3
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A modification of Tim Cooper's answer

```
$o = (object) array(
    'action1' => function() { echo "Fire 1\n"; },
    'action2' => function() { echo "Fire 2\n"; },
    'action3' => function() { echo "Fire 3\n"; }
);

$o->action2();
```